# OpenAM and CDSSO - how to configure

Tags: openam, opensso

I'm trying to set up OpenAM with CDSSO, but I cann't find the right setup.

### My environment looks like this:

OpenAM:

- version: 10.0.0
- few tomcat

  - behind loadbalancer 10.10.10.10:8000
  - availble by http://abc.xxx.com which redirects to http://sso.yyy.com or by http://sso.yyy.com

Apache with web agent

- apache version: Apache/2.2.15
- web agent version: Version: 3.0-04, Revision: 9150
- host have access to 10.10.10.10:8000, but not to http://abc.xxx.com or http://sso.yyy.com
- accessed via http://efg.xxx.com

End user / browser

- have access to http://sso.yyy.com, but not to 10.10.10.10:8000

### Tested configurations

#### Try 1

In web agent configuration I setup
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cdcservlet.url[0]=http://10.10.10.10:8000/opensso/cdcservlet

- in browser I have redirect to 10.10.10.10:8000/opensso/cdcservlet
  Location: http://10.10.10.10:8000/opensso/cdcservlet?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fefg.xxx.com%3A80%2F&
- in web agent log is

  am_web_do_cookie_domain_set(): setting cookie  iPlanetDirectoryPro=;Path=/.
  is_server_alive(): Connection timeout set to 2
  am_web_get_url_to_redirect: The goto_url and url before appending cdsso elements: [http://efg.xxx.com:80/] [http://10.10.10.10:8000/opensso/cdcservlet?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fefg.xxx.com%3A80%2F]
  process_access_redirect(): get redirect url returned AM_SUCCESS, redirect url [http://10.10.10.10:8000/opensso/cdcservlet?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fhttp://efg.xxx.com%3A80%2F&].
  process_access_redirect(): returning web result AM_WEB_RESULT_REDIRECT.
  process_request(): returning web result AM_WEB_RESULT_REDIRECT, data [http://10.10.10.10:8000/opensso/cdcservlet?goto=http%3A%2F%2Fhttp://efg.xxx.com%3A80%2F&]
  am_web_process_request(): Rendering web result AM_WEB_RESULT_REDIRECT
  am_web_process_request(): render result function returned AM_SUCCESS.

#### Try 2

In web agent configuration I setup
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cdcservlet.url[0]=http://sso.yyy.com/opensso/cdcservlet

- in browser I have
  403, You don't have permission to access /
- in web agent logs is

  am_web_do_cookie_domain_set(): setting cookie  iPlanetDirectoryPro=;Path=/.
  am_web_get_url_to_redirect: unable to find active Access Manager Auth server.
  process_access_redirect(): get redirect url returned AM_FAILURE, redirect url [NULL].
  process_access_redirect(): returning web result AM_WEB_RESULT_FORBIDDEN.
  process_request(): returning web result AM_WEB_RESULT_FORBIDDEN, data []
  am_web_process_request(): Rendering web result AM_WEB_RESULT_FORBIDDEN
  am_web_process_request(): render result function returned AM_SUCCESS.

### Questions

1. Is it possible to perform such a configuration?

In newer version of OpenAM (12.0.0 › OpenAM Administration Guide) I find
OpenAM Conditional Login URL (Not yet in OpenAM console)
CDSSO examples: com.forgerock.agents.conditional.login.url[0]= login.example.com|http://openam1.example.com/openam/cdcservlet, http://openam2.example.com/openam/cdcservlet, com.forgerock.agents.conditional.login.url[1]= signin.example.com|http://openam3.example.com/openam/cdcservlet, http://openam4.example.com/openam/cdcservlet

2. what does it mean "Not yet in OpenAM console". Can I set this directry in OpenDJ?
3. Is this configuration will work on older versions of OpenAM?
4. Is for web agent work failover similat to https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19636-01/819-6101/auto20/index.html?

Thanks in advance
kawu

Comment: Answer to 1) Yes that's possible.
I don't see why you would need conditional login URL feature, 3.0-04 agent might not even support this feature (question 3)

If agents can not access CDCServlet or LoginURL feature you need to disable the probing for it ... see OPENAM-3294

You are using LB for OpenAM, so no need for Agent failover.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1) Yes that's possible. I don't see why you would need conditional login URL feature, 3.0-04 agent might not even support this feature (question 3) If agents can not access CDCServlet or LoginURL feature you need to disable the probing for it ... see OPENAM-3294 You are using LB for OpenAM, so no need for Agent failover.